# How to change dates in string form to datetime format?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that contains dates in string format and I am trying to change the dates to a datetime format. The format the dates are currently in is "Month Day, Year" with no leading zero on the day, e.g. `'May 1, 2014'`.

I have tried a couple of methods below but I keep getting a value error when I use the `%-d` to represent no leading zeros:

```
parser = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%b %-d %Y')

# Original Kaggle Dataset
employee_df = pd.read_csv('employee_reviews.csv', 
                          encoding='ISO-8859-1', 
                          skipinitialspace=True, 
                          parse_dates=['dates'], 
                          date_parser=parser
                         )
```

```
# 2nd solution

employee_df = pd.read_csv('employee_reviews.csv', 
                          encoding='ISO-8859-1', 
                          skipinitialspace=True, 
                          parse_dates=['dates'], 
                          date_parser=pd.to_datetime('%b %-d %Y'))
```

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that `%-d` _would_ work, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior doesn't suggest that form, but e.g. `datetime.strptime("May 1, 2014", "%b %d, %Y")` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Update the parser with the following line of code

```
parser = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d, %Y')
```